# The output is showing undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
model.js:

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema =mongoose.Schema;

const CountryInfoSchema = new Schema({
    country_code:{type:String},
    country_name:{type:String},
    is_active:{type:Boolean},
    created_on:{ type: Date, default: Date.now },
    created_by:{type:String},
    updated_on:{ type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated_by:{type:String}
});

module.exports =mongoose.model('country',CountryInfoSchema);


Controller.js:

const countryModel= require("./../userDetailsModels/country-info");

var createCountryDetails =(req,res) =>{
    var countryinfo = new countryModel(req.body);
    countryinfo.save()
        .then(info => {
            res.send({
                country_code:req.body.country_code,
                country_name:req.body.country_name,
                is_active:req.body.is_active,
                created_by:req.body.created_by,
                updated_by:req.body.updated_by,
                created_on:info.created_on,
                updated_on:info.updated_on,
                id:info._id
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send({
                message:err
            });
        });

}


module.exports ={
    createCountryDetails: createCountryDetails,
}
```

In postman i test the api

req.body:

```
{
     "country_code":"IND",
    "country_name":"India",
   " is_active":true,
    "created_by":"SA",
    "updated_by":"SA"
}
```

getting output below like this

```
{
    "created_on": "2018-08-28T06:51:57.278Z",
    "updated_on": "2018-08-28T06:51:57.278Z",
    "id": "5b84f10d7ca3bf2654d6af39"
}
```

Other field country_code is  showing undefined.I don't know where is the mistake.While debugging i am getting all fields are undefined.i am using mongo db.This code was working before i can't able create data using api

I need output like below:

```
{
         "country_code":"IND",
        "country_name":"India",
       " is_active":true,
        "created_by":"SA",
        "updated_by":"SA",
        "created_on": "2018-08-28T06:51:57.278Z",
        "updated_on": "2018-08-28T06:51:57.278Z",
        "id": "5b84f10d7ca3bf2654d6af39"
    }
```

Comment: What's ur  `req.body` ??

Comment: {
  "country_code":"IND",
    "country_name":"India",
   " is_active":true,
    "created_by":"SA",
    "updated_by":"SA"
}

Comment: IS the above is output of console.log(req.body) in your controller file??

Comment: Print and see in ur controller file, my guess is ur req.body is undefined..

Comment: That's y u are getting undefined.. Did you added the middleware `bodyparser`??

Comment: yes i added bodyparser

Comment: i found solution .in postman  headers key values are unchecked.then i check the key values